# Is it possible to do a drush sql-sync of only certain tables?

Tags: drush

I have 4 environments between my local, dev, staging, and production.

A large amount of content is published to the staging environment on a daily basis, so that is the center of my workflow. Once content is QA'ed in staging it is then sql-sync'ed to production. This works fine at the moment. However, we're now going to allow for user registration/user generated content. Is there a way to push these content updates with sql-sync and never overwrite certain tables? Even more specifically, is there something I can place in drushrc.php that will always skip a list of tables across all environments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## YES

### If you know which tables you want to transfer

> `--tables-list`
>
> A comma-separated list of tables to transfer. Optional.

### If you know which tables you want to skip

> `--skip-tables-list`
>
> A comma-separated list of tables to exclude completely. Optional.

---

And here is how I know this:

```
$ drush help sql-sync
Copy and import source database to target database. Transfers via rsync.

Examples:
 drush sql-sync @prod @dev                 Copy the DB defined in sites/prod to the DB in sites/dev.


Arguments:
 from                                      Name of subdirectory within /sites or a site-alias.
 to                                        Name of subdirectory within /sites or a site-alias.


Options:
 --cache                                   Skip dump if result file exists and is less than "cache" hours old. Optional; default is 24 hours.
 --create-db                               Create a new database before importing the database dump on the target machine.
 --db-su=                            Account to use when creating a new database. Optional.
 --db-su-pw=                         Password for the "db-su" account. Optional.
 --dump-dir                                Directory to store sql dump files in when --source-dump or --target-dump are not used.  Takes precedence over --temp.
 --no-cache                                Do not cache the sql-dump file.
 --no-dump                                 Do not dump the sql database; always use an existing dump file.
 --no-ordered-dump                         Do not pass --ordered-dump to sql-dump.  sql-sync orders the dumpfile by default in order to increase the efficiency of rsync.
 --sanitize                                Obscure email addresses and reset passwords in the user table post-sync. Optional.
   --sanitize-password                     The password to assign to all accounts in the sanitization operation, or "no" to keep passwords unchanged.  Default is "password".
   --sanitize-email                        The pattern for test email addresses in the sanitization operation, or "no" to keep email addresses unchanged.  May contain replacement patterns %uid,
                                           %mail or %name.  Default is "user+%uid@localhost".
   --confirm-sanitizations                 Prompt yes/no after importing the database, but before running the sanitizations
 --skip-tables-key                         A key in the $skip_tables array. @see example.drushrc.php. Optional.
 --skip-tables-list                        A comma-separated list of tables to exclude completely. Optional.
 --source-database                         A key in the $db_url (D6) or $databases (D7+) array which provides the data.
 --source-db-url                           Database specification for source system to dump from.
 --source-dump                             Path to dump file. Optional; default is to create a temporary file.
 --source-remote-host                      Remote machine to run sql-dump file on. Optional; default is local machine.
 --source-remote-port                      Override sql database port number in source-db-url. Optional.
 --structure-tables-key                    A key in the $structure_tables array. @see example.drushrc.php. Optional.
 --structure-tables-list                   A comma-separated list of tables to include for structure, but not data. Optional.
 --tables-key                              A key in the $tables array. Optional.
 --tables-list                             A comma-separated list of tables to transfer. Optional.
 --target-database                         A key in the $db_url (D6) or $databases (D7+) array which shall receive the data.
 --target-db-url
 --target-dump
 --target-remote-host
 --target-remote-port
 --temp                                    Use a temporary file to hold dump files.  Implies --no-cache.
```

Comment: make sure you dont put spaces after the commas if you're transferring more than 1 table. If it has spaces it doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps `--skip-tables-list` is of interest to you. `drush help COMMAND` is your friend. You can set a global option in a `drush.rc` file to make this option hardcoded for every `sql-sync` for certain Site Aliases if you want. Because heaven forbid you sql-sync and forget to skip tables on some Friday at 5pm :(.

```
drush help sql-sync
Copy and import source database to target database. Transfers via rsync.

Examples:
 drush sql-sync @prod @dev                 Copy the DB defined in sites/prod to the DB in sites/dev.

Arguments:
 from                                      Name of subdirectory within /sites or a site-alias. 
 to                                        Name of subdirectory within /sites or a site-alias.

Options:
 --cache                                   Skip dump if result file exists and is less than "cache" hours old. Optional; default is 24 hours.                          
 --create-db                               Create a new database before importing the database dump on the target machine.                                             
 --db-su=                            Account to use when creating a new database. Optional.                                                                      
 --db-su-pw=                         Password for the "db-su" account. Optional.                                                                                 
 --dump-dir                                Directory to store sql dump files in when --source-dump or --target-dump are not used.                                      
 --no-cache                                Do not cache the sql-dump file.                                                                                             
 --no-dump                                 Do not dump the sql database; always use an existing dump file.                                                             
 --no-ordered-dump                         Do not pass --ordered-dump to sql-dump.  sql-sync orders the dumpfile by default in order to increase the efficiency of     
                                           rsync.                                                                                                                      
 --sanitize                                Obscure email addresses and reset passwords in the user table post-sync. Optional.                                          
   --sanitize-password                     The password to assign to all accounts in the sanitization operation, or "no" to keep passwords unchanged.  Default is      
                                           "password".                                                                                                                 
   --sanitize-email                        The pattern for test email addresses in the sanitization operation, or "no" to keep email addresses unchanged.  May contain 
                                           replacement patterns %uid, %mail or %name.  Default is "user+%uid@localhost".                                               
   --confirm-sanitizations                 Prompt yes/no after importing the database, but before running the sanitizations                                            
 --skip-tables-key                         A key in the $skip_tables array. @see example.drushrc.php. Optional.                                                        
 --skip-tables-list                        A comma-separated list of tables to exclude completely. Optional.                                                           
 --source-database                         A key in the $db_url (D6) or $databases (D7+) array which provides the data.                                                
 --source-db-url                           Database specification for source system to dump from.                                                                      
 --source-dump                             Path to dump file. Optional; default is to create a temporary file.                                                         
 --source-remote-host                      Remote machine to run sql-dump file on. Optional; default is local machine.                                                 
 --source-remote-port                      Override sql database port number in source-db-url. Optional.                                                               
 --structure-tables-key                    A key in the $structure_tables array. @see example.drushrc.php. Optional.                                                   
 --structure-tables-list                   A comma-separated list of tables to include for structure, but not data. Optional.                                          
 --tables-key                              A key in the $tables array. Optional.                                                                                       
 --tables-list                             A comma-separated list of tables to transfer. Optional.                                                                     
 --target-database                         A key in the $db_url (D6) or $databases (D7+) array which shall receive the data.                                           
 --target-db-url                                                                                                                                                       
 --target-dump                                                                                                                                                         
 --target-remote-host                                                                                                                                                  
 --target-remote-port                                                                                                                                                  
 --temp                                    Use a temporary file to hold dump files.  Implies --no-cache.
```

Comment: Seems we said the same, with less than a minute time difference. What can I say, don't know why mine was accepted... After all, I was few seconds slower.

Comment: @Molot no worries have a great week!

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the [Drush Commands page for sql-sync](http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-6x/sql/sql-sync) (or `drush sql-sync --help`) then you'll notice there is a parameter called `--skip-tables-list`.

> --skip-tables-list : A comma-separated list of tables to exclude completely. Optional.

To answer the second part of your question, you can also add an array to `drushrc.php` ([source](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.drushrc.php#L253-L260)):

```
/**
 * List of tables to be omitted entirely from SQL dumps made by the 'sql-dump'
 * and 'sql-sync' commands when the "--skip-tables-key=common" option is
 * provided on the command line.  This is useful if your database contains
 * non-Drupal tables used by some other application or during a migration for
 * example.  You may add new tables to the existing array or add a new element.
 */
```

In this instance you then pass the array key with `--skip-tables-key`:

> --skip-tables-key : A key in the $skip_tables array. @see example.drushrc.php. Optional.